# Why is $p^2-q^2 = p-q$ when $p+q = 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble to see why it is that:

$p^2-q^2 = p-q$ when $p+q = 1$

If I take a number for which $p+q \not= 1$, this doesn't hold. What's so special about the former case? Can someone take me through this, algebraically?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$p^2 - q^2 = (p-q)(p+q){}{}{}{}$$

Comment: Ah, thanks. :) Now I see why it simplifies to $(p-q)$ when $(p+q)=1$. I never thought of writing out the difference of the squares in that way. I should probably [practice factoring the difference of squares](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/multiplying-factoring-expression/factoring-special-products/e/factoring_difference_of_squares_1). Incidentally, I only just learned the name of this algebraic technique (from @ir7).

Answer (score 2):

Complementing the other answer, the formula has a name: Difference of two squares formula.

Moreover, it also goes the other way, if $p\not = q$. That is: if $p^2-q^2=p-q$ and $p\not=q$, then $p+q=1$.